# Append xml to existing xml in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file  as:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <condition>
            ....

            </condition>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

I have another XML in string type as :

```
<condition>
  <comparison compare="and">
    <operand idref="Agent" type="boolean" />
    <comparison compare="lt">
      <operand idref="Premium" type="float" />
      <operand type="int" value="10000" />
    </comparison>
  </comparison>
</condition>
```

I need to comment  the 'condition block' in the first xml and then append this second xml in place of it.
I did not try to comment the first block but tried to append the second xml in the first. I am able to append it to it but I am getting the '<' and '>' as 
&lt ; and &gt ; respectively as

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <condition>
            ....

            </condition>

                &lt;condition&gt;
 &lt;comparison compare="and"&gt;
&lt;operand idref="Agent" type="boolean"/&gt;
&lt;comparison compare="lt"&gt;
  &lt;operand idref="Premium" type="float"/&gt;
  &lt;operand type="int" value="10000"/&gt;
&lt;/comparison&gt;
&lt;/comparison&gt;
&lt;/condition&gt;
```

How do I convert this back to `<` and `>` rather than `lt` and `gt`?

And how do I delete or comment the `<condition>` block of the first xml below which I will append the new xml?

```
tree = ET.parse('basexml.xml')  #This is the xml where i will append
tree1 = etree.parse(open('newxml.xml'))  # This is the xml to append
xml_string = etree.tostring(tree1, pretty_print = True)  #converted the xml to string
tree.find('a/b/c').text = xml_string #updating the content of the path with this new string(xml)
```

I converted the 'newxml.xml' into a string  'xml_string' and then appended to the path a/b/c of the first xml

Comment: XMLs are easier to manipulate with a library designed for that.
try: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: tree = etree.parse(open('basexml.xml')  #This is the xml where i will append

Comment: @mzjn  

tree = ET.parse('basexml.xml')  #This is the xml where i will append
tree1 = etree.parse(open('newxml.xml'))  # This is the xml to append
xml_string = etree.tostring(tree1, pretty_print = True)
tree.find('a/b/c').text = xml_string

I converted the 'newxml.xml' into a string  'xml_string' and then appended to the path a/b/c of the first xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding newxml.xml, as a string, to the `text` property of the `<c>` element. That does not work. You need to add an `Element` object as a child of `<c>`.

Here is how it can be done:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# Parse both files into ElementTree objects
base_tree = ET.parse("basexml.xml")
new_tree = ET.parse("newxml.xml")

# Get a reference to the "c" element (the parent of "condition")
c = base_tree.find(".//c")

# Remove old "condition" and append new one
old_condition = c.find("condition")
new_condition = new_tree.getroot()
c.remove(old_condition)
c.append(new_condition)

print ET.tostring(base_tree.getroot())
```

Result:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <condition>
  <comparison compare="and">
    <operand idref="Agent" type="boolean" />
    <comparison compare="lt">
      <operand idref="Premium" type="float" />
      <operand type="int" value="10000" />
    </comparison>
  </comparison>
</condition></c>
  </b>
</a>
```